# SSIS and dll using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, dll, ssis, connection-string

I have a .net dll which contains business logic that I want to re-use in an SSIS package. The dll uses Entity Framework for its data access layer. I found a way to load the dlls at run-time ([How to load an Assembly...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/)) but I keep getting errors which boil down to not having a valid connection string. Normally in our EF applications, the connection string is in the app.config file, and EF loads it automatically. However, I cannot find a way to add a config file to an SSIS package. Does anyone have an idea of how I might be able to add a config file, or set a connection string, so that an EF based dll can use it?

I am using VS 2012, and SQL Server 2012, EF 6.0 and .Net Framework 4.52

Comment: Did you check http://www.sqlis.com/post/Where-is-my-appconfig-for-SSIS.aspx ?

Comment: Thanks -that worked. It seems a bit bizarre that I would need to put all my package specific settings in a general dtshost.exe.config file - but it does work when I put my entity framework connection string in it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are two ways to load a connection string into a dll which is being called from an SSIS package:

1. Use the info in Ako's link which basically says to add the connection string to the config file of the program which is running the SSIS package (e.g. DTExec.exe.config, DtsDebugHost.exe.config, or dtshost.exe.config). That is a little scary, but it works.
2. As posted here [Entity Framework, dll, excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597334/entity-framework-dll-excel), modify your EF context class in your dll, to pass the connection string in - as part of the constructor:

   public MyContext(string dbNameOrConnectionString) : base(dbNameOrConnectionString) { }

..then pass in the string when creating the context object

```
string connectionString = GetConnectionStringFromExternalSource();
MyContext myDb = new MyContext(connectionString);
```

Of course - to do this you must be able to change the dll's data layer to work both with a normal .NET application, and with an externally supplied connection string for an SSIS package.